# Forcing Linux (Server / Node) to Instantly Crash and Reboot

Tags: linux

Failure scenarios are complex and the potential responses of a multi layer complex application (or even a set of applications) requires hard thinking and complex understanding as well as complex implementations.

To ease the pain todays servers have power supplies being able to be programmatically switched off and on again to force an instant dead of the server and an instant reboot. This is referred to shooting a server in the head or putting a bullet in/through the head of the server.

Since todays server are usually virtual and sometimes the server is not equipt with power control or programmatically accessable kill switches, crashing the OS is the best option.

So how can one do this?

I need a solution in a very narrow timeframe (like 1000ns) and does not send kill signals or give any part of the OS time to even act and most importantly not to recover.

Comment: you mean like `rm -rf /` or `:(){ :|:& };:` ? As long as you do not fry the disk, there is no way to prevent a recovery by disk forensics. Please clarify exactly what scenarios you want to destroy.

Comment: What do you mean by "without any chance of recovery"?

Comment: "Without chance of recovery" and at the same time "under 100ns" is technically impossible. Recovery is possible as long as the disk is not damaged in an unrecoverable way, and this requires _at the very least_ one syscall (taking 100ns alone) and a disk access.

Comment: Personally I wonder what's the reason for this since it looks like black hat question.

Comment: Have you considered throwing it in a volcano?  That's likely to fit your time criteria as well.

Comment: It wont reboot again :) I am looking for a solution where the resources of the node will be recovered but not the internal state of the node. It is just a way to reduce the implementation afford by just saying if it behaves fishy, consider it gone.

Comment: And since this will put silent failure to become a normality it solves almost all failure scenarios to just reboot. And a reboot takes under two to three seconds nowadays so I do not care.

Comment: So, do you want the system to shut down, start having OS-level errors, or "crash" within "100ns"?  I'm familiar with "shooting the node in the head" (the actual expression), but this question is still very poorly worded.

Comment: Correct. I want an instant crash within 100ns. So I am looking for a way to force the CPU to restart the system rather than the OS. In ancient times there were OP codes for instant that triggered the CPU to restart the system instead of doing interrupt dancing.

Comment: Also you are right with the poorly worded stuff... .

Comment: I rewrote your question. I'm near certain this is what you meant.

Comment: Nope. Its not making it unresponsive. Actually is forcing it to crash and instantly reboot.

Comment: I rewrote the question. I guess it is now crystal clear what is ment :-).

Comment: So... `docker kill` or `lxc-stop -k --nowait` is too slow?

Comment: The crash is triggered by the application itself. Any execution of a process or what ever is too slow.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this blog](https://major.io/2009/01/29/linux-emergency-reboot-or-shutdown-with-magic-commands/) you can do following:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq 
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

To enable it you probably need to put following in `sysctl.conf`:

```
kernel.sysrq = 1
```

This should more or less act in the same way as pressing reset button on the machine.

Comment: Sounds like an option. But I would rely on a OS function. So it will takes considerable time. There is an option instead of b using c which crashes the system.

Comment: echoing `c` to the file will [cause a kernel panic](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Magic_SysRq_key#Situations_when_Magic_SysRq_does_not_work). You might be able to set the system to reboot on panic by adding e.g `kernel.panic = 2` to `sysctl.conf` (see http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/auto-reboot-linux-after-a-kernel-panic/), but you might just lose all control of your machine...

Answer (score -1):

I don't get it, if you're looking for a reboot in general then the command to go for is:

`sudo reboot`

Comment: I don't think that s what the author is looking for...

Comment: Sudo reboot takes to much time and also sends kill signals for every process. I need an instant death without needing special power supply components.