# Instantly Crashing A Linux OS Intel CPU Server And Forcing Reboot

Tags: linux, server, intel

Failure scenarios are complex and the potential responses of a multi layer complex application (or even a set of applications) requires hard thinking and complex understanding as well as complex implementations.

To ease the pain todays servers have power supplies being able to be programmatically switched off and on again to force an instant dead of the server and an instant reboot. This is referred to shooting a server in the head or putting a bullet in/through the head of the server.

Since todays server are usually virtual and sometimes the server is not equipt with power control or programmatically accessable kill switches, crashing the OS is the best option.

So how can one do this?

I need a solution in a very narrow timeframe (like 1000ns) and does not send kill signals or give any part of the OS time to even act and most importantly not to recover.

I am looking for a OPCode way. The fastest possible solution right now is relying on [SysRg|https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key] but the sequence is unclear. I would prefer a OP-Code method I can trigger by an application. Former Intel CPU had exceptional states where it triggers a soft reset based on hardware. I hope this is still possible today.

Comment: Can't you ask the hypervisor to stop/restart the VM?

Comment: Your question is unclear (and off-topic). Why do you ask? What is the motivation? Are you talking of virtual machines, or of real physical servers?

Comment: Why can't you use the Linux specific [reboot(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html) syscall? Why do you want a short microsecond timeframe, since Linux takes more than a second to reboot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing Linux (Server / Node) to Instantly Crash and Reboot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157305/forcing-linux-server-node-to-instantly-crash-and-reboot)

Answer (score 0):

What about kernel module which on injection create generic protection fault interrupt in kernel space? E.g. try to write to definitely forbidden memory areas - e.g. system call table.

Comment: Would that kill the OS and force the CPU to reboot?

Comment: Behavior will depend on configuration of kernel. IIRC, the default one is to print kernel trace and reboot. For sure you can configure different approach - e.g. reloading into another kernel for kdump.